# Microphone gets recognized by windows and driver software but other software doesnt recieve input

Tags: windows-10, drivers, microphone, audio-recording

All of a sudden my microphone stopped working on all Desktop Software in Windows 10. I have reinstalled all related drivers and updated anything that was needed. When I am in the driver software (Realtek HD Audio Manager) I can hear the microphone input when I set the output volume to high so I know it is not a hardware issue. But when I try to access it in any other software it just stays quiet and no input is recorded even though the correct microphone shows up in the settings.
Has anyone got an idea what could be the problem

Comment: I encountered this problem, too. Wasted an hour until I found this post. For future reference, the errors reported are dependant on the selected audio subsystem the *Windows Audio Session* reports `DEVICE_INITIALIZE: Access Denied`, but *DirectShow*  says `CREATECAPTUREBUFFER Error {0E7D21D9-C040-4F36-AEEF-CAC3C3CE6C10}`, which is the most non-informative error description I have ever seen. Most applications (Skype, Windows Audio Settings) will silently ignore these errors anyway, so you are simply stuck with a non-initialized input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

allow mic access in settings - privacy - microphone, new change in the latest windows 10 update 1803

Comment: Worked perfectly! The only guy on the internet who knows this haha thx

Comment: Why Windows?! Wish the sound settings had linked me to look at privacy issues.

Answer (score 0):

Seems not to be a system or hardware issue, considering whether your recording software or user profile have trouble.

Run Recording Audio troubleshooter

Uninstall your recording software.

Create a new local account.

Clean boot computer

Login with the new account and install your software, test microphone input.